# Is it safe to use EV de-charging cables?

Tags: batteries, electric-vehicles

My friend told me that an EV is a huge self-driving powerbank and that with proper cable I can charge my mobile phone, make a barbeque or work on my laptop outdoor.

After quite intensively searching the Internet I have found only **one** example of such cable:

https://allegro.pl/oferta/samochod-elektryczny-wtyczka-rozladowania-typ2-16a-12404985304

[image]

[image]

It says (an automatic Polish-to-English translation based on a very poor Polish text, made most likely automatically from Chinese original):

> Plug-and-Play, suitable for a wide range of electrical appliances. Discharge yourself anytime, anywhere. Small and portable, 5m cable, easy to carry. Mobile electric station for external power supply. Please check with your car manufacturer or your car owner's manual to see if your car has a discharge function before purchase, it needs Vehicle to Load (V2L) or Vehicle to Home (V2H) or Vehicle to Grind (V2G) support from your car. Inform us about the make and type of your car right after placing the order. We need this information to be compatible with your car.

As mentioned, this is the only example found by me. Other solutions allows doing something completely different, i.e. "converting" Type 2 socket in charging station into Schuko socket in order to charge a car equipped with Schuko socket as well (and the integrated on-board charging cable) from charging station itself, not from a home wall socket.

- [Allegro](https://allegro.pl/oferta/adapter-do-ladowania-ev-schuko-do-typ-2-torba-12028964143)
- [Amazon](https://www.amazon.pl/EV-Samochod%C3%B3w-Elektrycznych-1-Fazowy-%C5%81adowania/dp/B083WB6FFX?th=1)
- [AliExpress](https://pl.aliexpress.com/item/1005002886760356.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.main.3.60a41c8fRF0m3S&algo_pvid=c1ab3034-5456-4dbf-b53e-91a152b6051b&algo_exp_id=c1ab3034-5456-4dbf-b53e-91a152b6051b-1&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2212000022625814856%22%7D&pdp_npi=2%40dis%21PLN%21464.03%21269.12%21%21%21%21%21%402100b69816669443987143494d0725%2112000022625814856%21sea&curPageLogUid=F5avv1g5sene)

So, nothing about making barbecues using energy from your EV.

This makes me very doubtful and question, if this isn't another "wild Chinese idea" that will simply damage my EV.

Has anyone have any experience with such cable and with working in the depicted conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way will this work with most EVs. (It seems to already mention that in the description -- needing V2L.)

EV battery is direct current. To create alternating current, you need an inverter. To create it at 3600 W (which is 230 V 16 A), you need a very hefty inverter. Also ideally a sine wave inverter.

Some cars have the inverter built-in, such as Kia EV6 and Hyundai Ioniq 5. However, in this case you will get the cable with the car.

Other cars don't have an inverter. In this case, such a cable is not safe. Most likely, it won't work and you only wasted your money. Less likely, something will be damaged if you try to do something that cannot possibly work.

Such a small cable can't have an inverter built-in since a sine wave inverter of that capacity has a weight of 10 kg approximately, and requires active cooling with a fan (which I don't see in the cable). Also if you use such an inverter in wet environments, you may run into problems, such as rain getting inside the inverter from vents that are needed for air cooling.

Also even if the cable had a built-in inverter, it will not work with the car's AC-to-DC charger. Maybe it could work using DC charging, if the car has bidirectional DC charging support (vehicle-to-grid). But even if the car has V2G, then the cable would need to weigh 10 kg and solve the rain intrusion problem somehow.

The best place for the inverter is the car, since the car's body shields it from rain and it can have active cooling, and 10 kg additional weight in a car is next to nothing (EVs weigh regularly 2000kg). So when purchasing your next EV, be sure to ensure it has V2L functionality.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer and for solving all my doubts. Just to clarify. Does "inverter built-in" means the same as "V2L functionality"? If my next car will be Kia EV6 or Hyundai Ioniq 5 will I have a "driving pendrive functionality"? Sorry for making complex things such dumbly simple, but I am a very, very newbie to EVs. Thanks.

Comment: If you buy EV6 or Ioniq 5, then the car should come with the cable so you don't need to purchase a separate cable. You should obviously confirm from the dealer that in your market area, the feature is included.

Comment: @juhist *all* cars have the inverter. The frequency converter used for powering the motor is essentially an inverter. But it may not have the software or wiring required...